# Hibernate removes relation on update

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to define my @ManyToMany relationship with JPA Annotations so that relations are not removed when updating entity.

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity=Event.class, cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(
  name = "event_user", 
  joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), 
  inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "event_id")
)
private Set<Event> events;
```

and Event class

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy="events", targetEntity=User.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<User> attending;
```

I thought setting CascadeType.REMOVE would not trigger deletion when updating but when I call update on a user object, all its related events are removed.

This is from my DAO

```
@Override
public User update(User entity) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(entity);
    return entity;
}
```

When I call update on my entity, Hibernate does:

```
Hibernate: delete from event_user where user_id=?
```

Comment: You need to show more code. For all we know, you're clearing the user's event set and this is exactly what should be happening. Please show what you are doing to a User before you make the update() call, as well as any other relevant code.

Comment: `delete from event_user` won't delete the `Event`s. It will delete the rows from the join table. That has to happen because you are removing entries from the collection. Are `Event`s also being deleted?

Comment: The user is sent to the DAO from the service layer and initally from the controller where the user was retrived from a json object I guess the problem is that the user is never beeing loaded from the database? and that hibernate cant make out witch user it is to update on its own? or that relations perhaps do not pass in from the json data.

Answer (score 1):

The comments on your questions are correct so far. You obviously do not load the entity from the database before updating it. Hence, hibernate updates everything just as it finds it in your entity. So, load the entity (by id?), merge your changes and update it afterwards.

Btw you should also consider using the delete orphans annotation. You would hence make sure that events to a user would also get deleted when setting the event collection to null and not only when removing the entire user.

Comment: This seems to be the issue, thanks for pointing that out. Sometimes I dont want to load relations for the client, therefore the relationship is sent as a null value (although there are relations in the db). When updating the entity, Hibernate sees null/empty relations and deletes them from the database. I can load the entity and copy certain attributes but this leads to other issues (example: sometimes the relation is set from JSON). Been trying to find a solution for this behaviour, to connect Jackson and Hibernate in some way.

Comment: You might consider using data transfer objects rather than sending the entities. I know this is controversial, but I find it useful for such cases. Use Mapstruct, Dozer or any other tool to map between both.